# Memoir class: turn off section numbering but still have header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, numbering, memoir

Trying to get rid of auto display of section numbers within text (section title only), but still have a header that gives the section title (also sans number).  Can't seem to find this in memoir docs.  In other words, I want some of the behavior of \section and some of \section*

Answer (score 5):

Set `\setsecnumformat` to be empty (this suppresses the numbering for the titles in the body) and redefine `\sectionmark` appropriately (to suppress the numbering from the headings); for example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setsecnumformat{}
\def\sectionmark#1{\markboth{#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to turn off numbering for `\section`s and all lower levels of heading, then place this in your preamble:

```
\setsecnumdepth{chapter}
```

`\section` and `\section*` will continue to work as advertised, but simply without any numbering.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `\setsecnumformat{}` to the preamble of your document. That'll do. (See p.107 of [`memman`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf), the Memoir Class manual, for details.)

Comment: Not necessarily; this won't take care of suppressing the numbering from the headers.