# Sections : Suppress numbers but retain title in header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

I've found an answer to my question for a Memoir Class ([Memoir class: turn off section numbering but still have header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60137/memoir-class-turn-off-section-numbering-but-still-have-header)), but I can't get it to work for a book.

Basically, I want to suppress the numbering of sections, but I still want to be able to have my section names appear in my headers.

The code below works fine in section 2, but, in section 1, where I suppress the numbering, I also lose the header.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,blindtext}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \rightmark}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

% Global font
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}
\fontencoding{T1}
\fontfamily{ppl}
\fontsize{14}{18}
\selectfont

% Start the chapters here:

\chapter{Preface}

\section*{Section 1}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\section{Section 2}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

Comment: Not a real answer, but why not just use memoir for this application?

Comment: If you want to have entries in the toc as well, use https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy with the package `titlesec`.

Load it as

```
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
```

instead of loading `fancyhdr`.

Then, to have your section without printed numbers, define

```
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
```

and to have the headers like you want,

```
\newpagestyle{fancy}{
\setheadrule{0.4pt}
\sethead[\thepage][][\textsl{\MakeUppercase{\sectiontitle}}]% even
{\textsl{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter. \ \chaptertitle}}}{}{\thepage}% odd
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{}

\newpagestyle{fancy}{
\setheadrule{0.4pt}
\sethead[\thepage][][\textsl{\MakeUppercase{\sectiontitle}}]% even
{\textsl{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter. \ \chaptertitle}}}{}{\thepage}% odd
}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}

% Global font
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}
\fontencoding{T1}
\fontfamily{ppl}
\fontsize{14}{18}
\selectfont

% Start the chapters here:

\chapter{Preface}

\section{Section 1}

\blindtext
\blindtext

\section{Section 2}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is great; thanks very much.  I think I'll opt for this particular solution since it allows me to continue to use the standard \section tag, which then makes my text easier to cut and paste into other docs.

Comment: @JamesBejon You're welcome. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a new command

```
\newcommand\mysection[1]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \markright{\MakeUppercase{#1}}% for the header
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \rightmark}

\newcommand\mysection[1]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \markright{\MakeUppercase{#1}}% for the header
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Preface}
\mysection{Section 1}
\Blindtext[10]
\section{Section 2}
\Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

---

Or maybe you can use the [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) class `scrbook`. There is a command `\addsec` to get an unnumbered section that appears in the header and in the tableofcontents.

```
\documentclass[11pt,headsepline,chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage[pagestyleset=standard]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{}
\lohead{\leftmark}
\rehead{\rightmark}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Preface}
\addsec{Section 1}
\Blindtext[10]
\addsec{Section 2}
\Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

---

Or you can simple use

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

if only parts and chapters should be numbered.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \rightmark}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\section{Section 1}
\Blindtext[10]
\section{Section 2}
\Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: First solution works fine; thanks.  I still had numbered sections when I used the KOMA-Script solution though; maybe I did something wrong...

Comment: I thought there were both unnumbered and numbered sections in the document. But if only parts and chapters should be numbered, you can simple use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`.