# spurious dot in chapter/section headings

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I'd like not to have the dots in these pictures. Related questions haven't helped.

[image]

[image]

Here's the MWE. Maybe not absolutely minimal since it has features I want that may be related to the problem.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\pagestyle{ruled}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mwe
\setstocksize{3in}{5in} 
\settrimmedsize{3in}{5in} {*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.3in}{0.3in}{*}%%%%
\setulmarginsandblock{0.5in}{0.5in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\fixpdflayout

\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{}
\renewcommand\partnumberline[1]{}

% suppress section and chapter numbering
%\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{}
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{}

% Set chapter name on the left
\chapterstyle{section}
\begin{document}

\chapter{first}

Now is the time for all good persons to come to the aid of the
party. That will require enough text to 
\newpage
get to a second page.

\section{first section}

\lipsum{1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that `\chaptermark` is the villain here! It uses `...\thechapter.`, so `.` is left if `\thechapter` is empty

Comment: You can also Gonzalo's version here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60139/4778

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want numbered sections and chapters, don't issue the instructions

```
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{}
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{}
```

A pure-LaTeX solution would be to issue the instruction

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
```

Since you're using the `memoir` document class, as @daleif has pointed out in a comment, a memoir-specific solution would consist of issuing the instruction

```
\setsecnumdepth{none}
```

Moreover, if `\mainmatter` (and, presumably, `\frontmatter`) is in use, you should issue the instruction

```
\maxsecnumdepth{none}
```

Comment: Since this is memoir: `\setsecnumdepth{none} ` might be easier to understand. Also add `\maxsecnumdepth {none} ` is `\mainmatter ` is used

Comment: Works, with @daleif 's suggestions.

Comment: @daleif - Thanks for your memoir-specific suggestions! I've added them to the body of the answer.